# iOS/Swift: issues with UITableViewCell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height

I wrote a `UITableView` that has custom `UITableViewCell`, and the data loading and the table data population has no problem, but the Cell height is so wrong that the content of each cell is only half visible (see the attached screenshots)

[image: tableview] [image: cell xib]

I have a `.xib` file (as show in the second screenshot above) for the `UITableViewCell` and have written a class that overrides the `UITableViewCell` class with the `layoutSubviews()` implementation below, in which I used the `[Neon][3]` library to do the positioning/layout of the UI elements:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true


        avatarImage.anchorInCorner(.TopLeft, xPad: 2, yPad: 2, width: 15, height: 15)
        postedByUsername.align(.ToTheRightCentered, relativeTo: avatarImage, padding: 1, width: 190, height: 15)

        timeAgo.anchorInCorner(.TopRight, xPad: 2, yPad: 2, width: 130, height: 15)

        questionTitle.alignAndFill(align: .UnderMatchingLeft, relativeTo: avatarImage, padding: 3)
        firstAttachedImage.align(.ToTheRightMatchingTop, relativeTo: questionTitle, padding: 3, width: 40, height: 40)

        self.answerButton.setFAText(prefixText: "", icon: FAType.FAReply, postfixText: "2", size: 14, forState: .Normal)
        self.commentButton.setFAText(prefixText: "", icon: FAType.FACommentO, postfixText: "1", size: 14, forState: .Normal)
        self.likeButton.setFAText(prefixText: "", icon: FAType.FAHeartO, postfixText: "10", size: 14, forState: .Normal)

        answerCommentLikeStackView.align(.UnderMatchingLeft, relativeTo: questionTitle, padding: 3, width: 190, height: 30)

        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()        
    }
```

In my UITableViewController implementation, I set the cell/row height like below:

```
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
        self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine

        // disable horizontal scroll
        self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height)
```

But the cell height is still wrong, what else can I do to make the height look right?

Comment: I've had issues with table cell heights too. Do you have a delegate for your table view?

Comment: yes, I do have a delegate implemented for my uitableview for the `select` action

Comment: Did you implement optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting tableView.rowHeight = x, try overriding the heightForRowAtIndexPath method instead:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPathindexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

This should get called for every cell the table view renders and resize it accordingly.

Comment: this works after I write a custom function that returns the height for each cell depending on the character counts in the title UILabel :)

Comment: That's good news. Do you have a multi-line label in your cell? If so, just using constraints inside your prototype cell should be sufficient with the code above. I know there used to be a bug in iOS/Obj-C where multi-line labels would calculate their height incorrectly - even with the correct constraints. Not sure if this is still an issue, but I have a feeling that is what you are seeing. Regardless, it is slightly annoying that you have to do the calculation yourself, but you gotta do what you gotta do I guess

Answer (score 1):

I like using the cellForRowAtIndexPath function. This way your rowHeight gets set in the same function that fills up the table with data:

```
//Fills up the tableview with data
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell

    //This is where the magic is happening
    tableView.rowHeight = 75;

    return cell
}
```